# IFormFile always null (ASP.NET Core with MVC/Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app attempting to upload an IFormFile. However, the IFormFile is always null. None of the other solutions I've found have solved this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Model

```
public class EmailForm
{
    [Display(Name = "Add a picture")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,png,gif,jpeg,bmp,svg")]
    public IFormFile SubmitterPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Contribute([Bind("SubmitterPicture")] EmailForm model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
}
```

View

```
        <form method="post" asp-action="Contribute" asp-antiforgery="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <div class="form-group" >
                <div class="col-md-2">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubmitterPicture)</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="file" name="SubmitterPicture" id="SubmitterPicture" />
    </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Contribute" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. How do you know it is coming as null ? Did you put a breakpoint in your action method and inspected ?

Comment: Yes. I put a breakpoint in the Contribute method and found that the SubmitterPicture object is always null. So for some reason, this binding isn't working properly.

Comment: I'm faced with the same issue. I've followed 3 tutorials so far, specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/uploading-files but I my viewmodel property is always null. Is there maybe some code that needs to be configure in the startup class?

Comment: @C.H. I found the issue. If you submit a form with one input you should be fetching the variable in the parameters because the post doesn't make use of the viewmodel in this case (that's my assumption). As soon as you submit more than one property in your form your viewmodel will be populated. See my answer below. +1 to the OP.

Answer (score 54):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

The multipart form data is the key.

Comment: The code in the question already has enctype="multipart/form-data

Comment: I had a similar upload problem. After adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form everything worked! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 11):

You can alternatively get the file from the `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` and get rid of the `IFormFile` interface in your model. I recommend this method as I believe that files have nothing to do with data models.

The example would be:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //Please note that if no form data is posted
    // HttpContext.Request.Form will throw an exception
    if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0] != null) {
        var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Your Path", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)) {
            file.CopyTo(fs);
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

If this method also fails, that means there is something wrong with the `multipart` request.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot this afternoon and let you know what happens.

Comment: Yup - also fails. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong with the multipart request, or even where to start? This is an area of the stack I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @C.H. : Remove the `asp-antiforgery="true"` or set it to false, and let's see what happens. By the way, try to upload a small file (small text file at 1KB), maybe the request max length limit is exceeded.

Comment: @C.H.: And try `File[0]` instead of 'File["Name"]'.

Comment: None of these made a difference. If I drill into the form request, I see that the count of "Files" is 0, which makes sense based on the error I'm getting. What doesn't make sense is WHY it's zero.

Comment: @C.H. Specify a name attribute in your view, for example <input name="File1" type="file" class="form-control" /> and then in your controller you can use: HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.GetFile("File"). I prefer this method for the same reason as Transcendent does.

Answer (score 9):

After sitting with the same problem for hours I found the solution.

**The Problem:**

Submitting a single input in a form.

**The Conclusion:**

Basically in your html form this won't work if you only have one input besides the submit button. My property was no longer null as soon I added another property on my viewModel and another input in my form.

I hope this helps someone else.

**Razor Page HTML:**

```
@page
@model SomeModel

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
            <input asp-for="Input.SingleInput" type="file" class="form-control" />
            <input asp-for="Input.AnotherInput" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Razor Page Code Behind:**

```
public class SomeModel: PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public SomeViewModel Input { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {

        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            // This won't be null.
            var showMeSomething = Input.SingleInput;

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
```

**SomeViewModel:**

```
public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public IFormFile SingleInput{ get; set; }
        public string AnotherInput{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that worked for me. It started working fine from my integration tests, postman etc, only if IFormFile is within another class. None of the examples or documentation seem to mention this

Answer (score 4):

I found that by providing names on my html form, I was able to map to parameters (ASP.NET Core 2.1):

Client side:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="...">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" required />
    <input type="password" name="myPass" required />
    <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>
```

Server side:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IFormFile myFile, [FromForm]string myPass)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works only when "name" is used instead of "asp-for".

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, if anyone working in .Net Core 2.1 and are using `asp-for` inorder bind the model for your input elements, then do not give name & id properties for that `<input>` elements. Ideally, the `InputTagHelper` upon the rendering on the browser generates the `name and id` properties with their values. If you give the same value for name & id w.r.t Model class, then everything works fine. Else, system doesn't know to which model property it should bind.
Better approach is not to give id and name on the `<input>`
Below is the sample code.

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm" asp-action="UploadExcel" method="post">

                <div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-sm row ">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 uploadDiv" style="display: flex !important">
                        <label asp-for="FileName" class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="font-size: 15px; max-width: fit-content ">File Name :</label>
                        <input asp-for="FileName" class="form form-control fileName"
                               type="text"
                               placeholder="Enter your file name" />
<!--File upload control-->
                        <label asp-for="FileName" class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="font-size: 15px; max-width: fit-content ">Attachment :</label>
                        <input asp-for="File" required class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="File Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" form-group form-group-lg form-group-sm row">
                    <span asp-validation-for="FileName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class=" form-group form-group-lg form-group-sm row">
                    <small>Please upload .xls or .xlxs or json or xml formatted files only</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-sm row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="fileUploadButton" value="Upload" />
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-Gray" name="result" id="resetButton" value="Reset" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a asp-action="DownloadTemplate" asp-controller="Download" title="Click to download template">Import Batch Transactions Template</a>
            </form>
```

Model.cs

```
public class ExcelUploadViewModel
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the FileName
        /// </summary>
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "FileName is required")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "File is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [FromForm(Name = "File")]
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Upon Submit[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine and it should work as long as you are using the same version of code you posted on the question. I have a very strong feeling that you are getting `false` for the `ModelState.IsValid` expression and hence seeing the some sort of unexpected behavior.

The `FileExtensions` data annotation is supposed to be used with `String` type properties, not with `IFormFile` type properties. Because of this reason, the `IsValid` returns false.

So remove that from your view model.

```
public class EmailForm
{
    [Display(Name = "Add a picture")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile SubmitterPicture { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a relevant GH issue and explanation from one of the team member, for your reference.

[FileExtensions Data annotation invalid ModelState #5117](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5117)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. The code is getting past the validation of the model and is failing when attempting to read the file. The SubmitterPicture is always null. If I try the same code with any simpler data type (i.e., bool, int, string), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the fix was to make sure the element of "input type="file"" had an id and name set. Then, in the controller, set the IFormFile parameter name to be exactly the same, case as well.
G-luck

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below to my controller fixed the issue for me.  It was because my file was large. Adjust the limits as needed.

```
 [RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```